# What is causing large jumps in training accuracy and loss between epochs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

In training a neural network in Tensorflow 2.0 in python, I'm noticing that training accuracy and loss change dramatically between epochs.  I'm aware that the metrics printed are an average over the entire epoch, but accuracy seems to drop significantly after each epoch, despite the average always increasing.

The loss also exhibits this behavior, dropping significantly each epoch but the average increases.  Here is an image of what I mean (from Tensorboard):

[image: strange training behavior]

I've noticed this behavior on all of the models I've implemented myself, so it could be a bug, but I want a second opinion on whether this is normal behavior and if so what does it mean?

Also, I'm using a fairly large dataset (roughly 3 million examples).  Batch size is 32 and each dot in the accuracy/loss graphs represent 50 batches (2k on the graph = 100k batches). The learning rate graph is 1:1 for batches.

Comment: Perhaps your batch size is too small

Comment: @Chris how would a small batch size cause this behavior?

Comment: if the batch doesn't contain enough samples to represent the population, it may optimize on the subset, and when a new batch is fetched it will see data that it had not optimized for and the error will spike.

Comment: @Chris if that is true, then how would the average loss and accuracy increase throughout the epoch, and then be dramatically lower at the start of a new epoch?

Comment: If your dataset has 3M examples, and from the plot, I can see that each epoch has around 2k steps, assuming you record the loss after each step. That means your batch size is larger than 1k. It's usually impossible. So what's your batch size and size of training data?

Comment: Batch size was 32, and each step in the graph is represented with the batch number divided by 50 (so 2k steps is actually 100k batches).  The learning rate however is just the number of batches on the x axis.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical here - Does it really matters ? Is it saw-tooth or just a smooth grow of accuracy ? In your given picture accuracy grows in logarithmic way with `R^2 = 0.73`. Even if you will get R squared 0.99 - what's the point of it ? It will be still logarithmic one. And is perfect inverse of learning rate. So this adjustment has no real business value, IMHO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems this phenomenon comes from the fact that the model has a high batch-to-batch variance in terms of accuracy and loss.  This is illustrated if I take a graph of the model with the actual metrics per step as opposed to the average over the epoch:

[image]

Here you can see that the model can vary widely. (This graph is just for one epoch, but the fact remains).

Since the average metrics were being reported per epoch, at the beginning of the next epoch it is highly likely that the average metrics will be lower than the previous average, leading to a dramatic drop in the running average value, illustrated in red below:

[image]

If you imagine the discontinuities in the red graph as being epoch transitions, you can see why you would observe the phenomenon in the question.

TL;DR The model has a very high variance in it's output with respect to each batch.

Comment: It seems like you are saying your accuracy drops at the beginning of each epoch because you reset the running average loss. It seems like it should be the opposite - once you no longer have earlier, lower accuracies bringing down the average, you should see an upward spike in accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

I have just newly experienced this kind of issue while I was working on a project that is about object localization. For my case, there was three **main** candidates.

- I have used no shuffling in my training. That creates a loss increase after each epoch.
- I have defined a new loss function that is calculated using IOU. It was something like;

  ```
  def new_loss(y_true, y_pred):
      mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) 
      iou = calculate_iou(y_true, y_pred) 
      return mse + (1 - iou)
  ```

  I also suspect this loss may be a possible candidate of increase in loss after epoch. However, I was not able to replace it.
- I was using an *Adam* optimizer. So, a possible thing to do is to change it to see how the training affected.

## Conclusion

I have just changed the *Adam* to *SGD* and shuffled my data in training. There was still a jump in the loss but it was so minimal compared without a change. For example, my loss spike was ~0.3 before the changes and it became ~0.02.

**Note**

I need to add there are lots of discussions about this topic. I tried to utilize the possible solutions that are possible candidates for my model.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  I'm currently testing to see if the jumps are an artifact of noisy output of the model (large variance in accuracy between batches) by stripping out the averaging of the metrics as it trains.  I'll use these suggestions to see if it ultimately reduces the variance of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too, turned out that one of the input variables had outliers (1:10000 ratio), with values way out of the allowed range (max value 100X larger than expected).